# Unable to navigate to steps from specflow scenarios after pressing F12

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper, bdd, specflow, gherkin

Example consider simple example

```
Given the JoeDoe user is associated to an existing staff account with the following information
  | Field       | Value         |
  | First Name  | Joe           |
  | Last Name   | Doe           |
```

in my VS2015, the **Given, Field and Value** keywords are not displayed in different color. When I press F12 unable to navigate to step definition, though steps are available. I restarted VS and also my machine, but nothing turns positively

Comment: Did you install the Visual Studio Extension for SpecFlow? https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c74211e7-cb6e-4dfa-855d-df0ad4a37dd6

Comment: yes Andreas, its installed and no errors in it. Doubled checked now

Comment: is the specflow nuget package installed in the test project?

Comment: Yes latest version 2.1.0

Comment: If your resharper installation is set up for IntelliJ keyboard shortcuts, then you get this issue. Ctrl-Alt-Shift-S will navigate to the step definitions, regardless of resharper settings.

Comment: Sorry sam, it doesn't works as well. I am getting another error when I right click on a feature file and click "Run custom tool". Error message is "Cannot find custom tool 'SpecflowSingleFileGenerator' on this system"

Comment: And I restart VS after each changes

Comment: then you do not have the visual studio extension installed, or it is corrupted somehow.

Comment: OMG!!!! I verified ExtensionsandUpdates in VS. Specflow was disabled. Many thanks sam

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems, luckily our QA team with lot of daily experience with SpecFlow could help me resolve this issue. Sometimes following steps help:

1. go to your temp folder (`%Temp%`)
2. there are several files called `...SpecFlow...` -> remove them
3. restart Visual Studio

**-> it works!**

if this still does not work, you can try as well Disable and Enable the SpecFlow feature extension and restart Visual Studio.

good luck...

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because the feature files (.feature and .feature.cs) were not included in the project. I had to revert the csproj once.